# Return 302 in Web Crawler

Tags: python

After I simulate to log in, when I try to post the original website, it returns 302. When I open the original website in Chrome, it returns 415.

I tried several ways:

session.post(url,headers = headers,data = data)

requests.post(url,headers = headers,data = data)

urllib.request.urlopen.read(url).decode()

```py
import requets
import json
header = {'Host': 'sty.js118114.com:8080',
          'Connection': 'keep-alive',
          'Content-Length': '8188',
          'Accept': '*/*',
          'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36',
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain;charset=UTF-8;application/xml',
          'Origin': 'http://sty.js118114.com:8080',
          'Referer':
'http://sty.js118114.com:8080/Report/report/movecar_list.html',
          'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
          'Accept-Language': 'zh-CN,zh;q=0.9',
          'Cookie': cookie_name + '=' + cookie_value
}
data = {"calling_no":"","begin_time":"","end_time":"","called_car_no":""}
res = requests.post(target,data = json.dumps(data),headers = header)
print(res.content.decode())
```

I expect the content must be the json version or html version so that I can use re model or xpath to get the infomation I want.(without any redirects

Lastly, I provide the necessary infomation about the problem:

```
Chrome Network

General

Request URL: http://sty.js118114.com:8080/Report/movecar/list/1/10

Request Method: POST

Status Code: 200 OK

Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8888

Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers

Content-Length: 8150

Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

Date: Thu, 22 Aug 2019 00:47:51 GMT

Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

Request Headers

Accept: */*

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9

Content-Length: 66

Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8;

Cookie: JSESSIONID=0A474B00017BFFD89A515B336F482905

Host: sty.js118114.com:8080

Origin: http://sty.js118114.com:8080

Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Referer: http://sty.js118114.com:8080/Report/report/movecar_list.html

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36

(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36

X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

Request Payload

{calling_no: "", begin_time: "", end_time: "", called_car_no: ""}

begin_time: ""
called_car_no: ""
calling_no: ""
end_time: ""

Fiddler Inspectors Raw

POST http://sty.js118114.com:8080/Report/movecar/list/1/10 HTTP/1.1

Host: sty.js118114.com:8080

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 66

Accept: */*

X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 

(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36

Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8;

Origin: http://sty.js118114.com:8080

Referer: http://sty.js118114.com:8080/Report/report/movecar_list.html

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.9

Cookie: JSESSIONID=0A474B00017BFFD89A515B336F482905

{"calling_no":"","begin_time":"","end_time":"","called_car_no":""}

Response Raw

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8

Date: Thu, 22 Aug 2019 00:27:59 GMT

Content-Length: 8150
```

Comment: _when I try to post the original website, it returns 302_ Why is that a problem?  It's very common to return a redirect in response to a POST.

Comment: I am trying to obtain the infomation on the target website. But I failed to get it because it returns 302 and asked me to log in again(redirect to another website)